# Conditional expression in a dataset parameter in JasperSoft

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, conditional-statements

I have a `.jrxml` report connected with MongoDB. Inside this reports, I have a table with many Dataset parameter in order to create dynamically the query. Unfortunately, I have problems with one of this parameters, it looks like:

```
($P {
    Owner
} == null || $P {
    Owner
}.equals("")) ? new String(""): ($P {
    Owner
}.equals("Pool")) ? "$and:[\"OpnPrps.CurAgtNme\":null,\"Nms.CloAgt\":null]" : "$or:[\"OpnPrps.CurAgtNme\":\"" + $P {
    Owner
} + "\",\"Nms.CloAgt\":\"" + $P {
    Owner
} + "\"]"
```

My problem is that when I preview my reports, the `$and`, `$or` part of my query can't be executed and I have the following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: {
    'findQuery': {
        "OlaDat": {
            '$lte': {
                "$date": 1434438846714
            },
            '$gt': {
                "$date": 1402902732089
            }
        },
        * * $and: ["OpnPrps.CurAgtNme": null, "Nms.CloAgt": null],
        * *
        "Nms.Src": "e-mail"
    }
```

Is there any way to change these conditions in order to get evaluable values inside a dataset parameter?

Comment: Ok I found the mistake myself, the problem was I missed two { } between objects. $and:[{"OpnPrps.CurAgtNme":null},{"Nms.CloAgt":null}]